# Run Task on Success but not on Skipped

Tags: python, airflow

I have a few tasks in AirFlow that I want to trigger only if the previous ones have succeeded and not skipped. According to AirFlow documentation, if I skip a task and the next one is set to 'all_success' it will be triggered anyway. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
my_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_id',
    python_callable=my_func,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    dag=my_dag)
```

http://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules

> One must be aware of the interaction between trigger rules and skipped
>   tasks in schedule level. Skipped tasks will cascade through trigger
>   rules all_success and all_failed but not all_done, one_failed,
>   one_success, none_failed, none_skipped and dummy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can modify the branching example given in the documents. On one branch first trigger on none_skipped followed by the tasks you want if none_skipped and all_success. The other branch will by default just be all_success and will branch around the ones you only want done if there was none_skipped.

```
run_this_first = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)
branching = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching', dag=dag,
    python_callable=lambda: 'none_skipped_branch'
)

none_skipped_branch = DummyOperator(task_id='none_skipped_branch',trigger_rule='none_skipped', dag=dag)
none_skipped_and_all_success = DummyOperator(task_id='none_skipped_and_all_success', dag=dag)

branch_false = DummyOperator(task_id='branch_false', dag=dag)

join = DummyOperator(task_id='join', dag=dag)

run_this_first >> branching
branching >> none_skipped_branch >> none_skipped_and_all_success >> join
branching >> branch_false >> join
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution! Thanks Bill!